# ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException when trying to access parameter annotations for inner class constructor via reflection

Tags: java, reflection, java-8, aspectj

I am trying to perform null checks on my methods using simple custom @NotNull annotation i.e.
I declare method as `myMethod(@NotNull String name, String description)` and when someone calls this method with null value passed as the 'name' argument an exception is thrown.

I already have an implementation of a simple aspect using aspectj. This solution works quite well for me. The one exception is constructors of inner classes. In such case the aspect crashes because of an exception inside java.lang.reflect.Parameter:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 1
    at java.lang.reflect.Parameter.getDeclaredAnnotations(Parameter.java:305)
    at java.lang.reflect.Parameter.declaredAnnotations(Parameter.java:342)
    at java.lang.reflect.Parameter.getAnnotation(Parameter.java:287)
    at java.lang.reflect.Parameter.getDeclaredAnnotation(Parameter.java:315)
    at ValidationAspect.checkNotNullArguments(ValidationAspect.java:22)
    at OuterClass$InnerClass.<init>(OuterClass.java:4)
    at OuterClass.constructInnerClass(OuterClass.java:14)
    at Main.main(Main.java:5)
```

Simplified implementation:

Aspect:

```java
import org.aspectj.lang.JoinPoint;
import org.aspectj.lang.annotation.Aspect;
import org.aspectj.lang.annotation.Before;
import org.aspectj.lang.annotation.Pointcut;
import org.aspectj.lang.reflect.ConstructorSignature;

import java.lang.reflect.Parameter;

@Aspect
public class ValidationAspect {

  @Pointcut("execution(*.new(.., @NotNull (*), ..))")
  private void anyConstructorWithNotNullParam() {}

  @Before("anyConstructorWithNotNullParam()")
  public void checkNotNullArguments(JoinPoint joinPoint) {
    ConstructorSignature signature = (ConstructorSignature) joinPoint.getSignature();
    Object[] args = joinPoint.getArgs();
    Parameter[] params = signature.getConstructor().getParameters();

    for(int i = 0; i < args.length; i++) {
      if(params[i].getDeclaredAnnotation(NotNull.class) != null) {
        if (args[i] == null) {
          throw new IllegalArgumentException("Illegal null argument");
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Annotation:

```java
import java.lang.annotation.ElementType;
import java.lang.annotation.Retention;
import java.lang.annotation.RetentionPolicy;
import java.lang.annotation.Target;

@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Target({ ElementType.PARAMETER})
public @interface NotNull { }
```

Test class:

```java
public class OuterClass {

  public class InnerClass {
    public InnerClass(
        @NotNull String name
    ) {
      System.out.println(String.format("Construct inner class with name: %s", name));
    }
  }

  public InnerClass constructInnerClass(
      String name
  ) {
    return new InnerClass(name);
  }
}
```

Usage:

```java
public class Main {

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    OuterClass outObj = new OuterClass();
    outObj.constructInnerClass("myName");
  }
}
```

As far as I can tell, this is caused by java passing the enclosing class object as the first argument to the constructor of the inner class (which I was told is standard behavior). The problem is, that `params[i].executable.getParameterAnnotations()` does not seem to know about the additional argument and returns annotations only for the "normal" parameters

I feel like this is a bug in either aspectj or java.lang.reflection. But as I cannot find any bug report for this, it seems more likely to me that I am doing something wrong. The app runs on java 8 (tried multiple different builds of the oracle jdk and the last openjkd build) and aspectj 1.8.13 (but tried also 1.9.4).

So my question(s): Is this a known bug? Is there some flaw in my implementation? Is there some workaround? (I guess it would not be that hard to match the annotations to the parameters manually. But as I have very limited knowledge about java reflection, I am not really able to foresee the consequences).

Edited: provided working example

Comment: Please provide an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), i.e. at least one or more complete applications classes reproducing the problem and of course also your pointcut definitions for `anyConstructorWithNotNullParam()` and `anyMethodWithNotNullParam()`. Nobody can help you if the cannot understand and reproduce your problem. You don't know why your solutions doesn't work, so how can you know it is in the code snippet you share and not elsewhere?

Comment: OK, I modified the question to contain simplified implementation with the same problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Okay, I was too curious and played around with my own MCVE. I could rule out AspectJ as the culprit and pinned the problem down to a JDK/JRE problem:

The thing with inner (non-static) class constructors is that their first parameter is always an instance of the outer object. Java 8 - I tried with both 1.8.0_152 and 1.8.0_211 - contains a reflection off-by-one bug. Basically it moves the annotations of real inner constructor parameters one index up, e.g. the annotation parameters for the first constructor argument are stored in index 0 which actually should contain the annotations for the outer object instance. My sample code explains it better, I guess:

```java
package de.scrum_master.app;

import static java.lang.annotation.ElementType.PARAMETER;
import static java.lang.annotation.RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME;

import java.lang.annotation.Retention;
import java.lang.annotation.Target;

@Retention(RUNTIME)
@Target(PARAMETER)
public @interface NotNull {}
```

```java
package de.scrum_master.app;

import java.lang.annotation.Annotation;
import java.lang.reflect.Constructor;
import java.lang.reflect.Parameter;

public class Application {
  class Inner {
    public Inner(@NotNull String text) {
      System.out.println("Constructing inner with " + text);
    }
  }

  public static void main(String[] args) throws NoSuchMethodException, SecurityException {
      Constructor<Inner> constructor = Inner.class.getConstructor(Application.class, String.class);
      System.out.println(constructor);
      for (Parameter parameter : constructor.getParameters()) {
        System.out.println("  " + parameter);
        for (Annotation annotation : parameter.getAnnotations())
          System.out.println("    " + annotation);
      }
  }
}
```

This reproduces your problem for JDK 8:

```
public de.scrum_master.app.Application$Inner(de.scrum_master.app.Application,java.lang.String)
  de.scrum_master.app.Application arg0
    @de.scrum_master.app.NotNull()
  java.lang.String arg1
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 1
    at java.lang.reflect.Parameter.getDeclaredAnnotations(Parameter.java:305)
    at java.lang.reflect.Parameter.getAnnotations(Parameter.java:333)
    at de.scrum_master.app.Application.main(Application.java:19)
```

But if you run with JDK 11 (I used 11.0.2) everything works as expected, also if I use an aspect with an advice like yours:

```
public de.scrum_master.app.Application$Inner(de.scrum_master.app.Application,java.lang.String)
  de.scrum_master.app.Application arg0
  java.lang.String arg1
    @de.scrum_master.app.NotNull()
```

I haven't bothered to look through all JDK release notes in order to find out whether this was fixed on purpose or by chance and in which JDK version (9, 10, 11), but at least I can tell you that after an update to JDK 11 you should be fine.

Comment: Seems to be fixed since JDK 9.

Comment: I agree, as can be tested on [JDoodle](https://www.jdoodle.com/a/1eQ1). Just play with the JDK version and change from 8 to 9 or 10.